# How to use Ruby and C# together in .Net?

Tags: c#, ruby

So far here's what I've done, and I'm not really sure it's meant to work, but well, better try something than doing nothing. I've added a Ruby class in my Winform project and it looks like this:

```
    class My_Ruby_Class
        def initialize(number)
            @number = number
            change_number()
        end

        def change_number
            @number*= 2
        end

        def get_number
            return @number
        end
    end
```

So later in my c# MainForm.cs I type:

```
namespace ruby_in_dotNet_test_01
{

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int number = 2;

            My_Ruby_Class test = new My_Ruby_Class(number);

            int number2 = test.get_number();

        }
    }
}
```

Very interestingly the intellisense seems to detect my ruby class and even helps me to fill the areas as I type, so it seems to me I'm on the right path. However it doesn't compile. The compiler error seems to be related to a missing type or namespace. I tried to surround my ruby class between the 'module ruby_in_dotNet_test_01' block but no success.

I'm confused, maybe there's only one small detail I'm not doing properly, or maybe this approach isn't meant to work at all?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to do won't work out-of-the box (define ruby code in a file and directly use it from C# and still get strong typing and Intellisense). Did you forget that Ruby is a weakly typed language?

You could use IronRuby to call ruby code from C#. Here's a [`step-by-step article`](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2010/09/using-ruby-classes-in-c-with-ironruby/) illustrating the process. And here's a [`screencast`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7DyIU3wzdY) you could watch.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to the other answer written by Darin Dimitrov, I just found this [step-by-step article](http://www.blossomsoft.com/gamezopher/2013/01/hello-world-program-using-ironruby/), it explains how to call ruby code from C# in a very friendly way.

Comment: Congrats, the link is dead and no info in your answer. ;P